# Having some trouble with inverse Laplace tranform

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

How to solve this using inverse Laplace transform?

1/[($s$+1)($s$+2)$^4$]

I though of this solution which is $A$/($s$+1) + $B$/($s$+2) + $C$/($s$+2)$^2$ + $D$/($s$+2)$^3$ + $E$/($s$+2)$^4$

Then I can start by finding $A$ when $s$ = -1 and $E$ when $s$ = -2. 
I guess finding $E$ also means finding $B$, $C$ & $D$ using some sort of an equation?

Comment: You are on the right track $-1/(s+2)-1/(s+2)^2-1/(s+2)^3-1/(s+2)^4+1/(s+1)$. Then use item 23: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf or crank it out using the definition of the inverse Laplace.

Comment: Use [Heaviside's "cover-up" method](http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/ma225/handouts/heavyside.pdf) for example or look [Partial fractions decomposition - Methods Survey](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txtd/3/txe3db3i.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{(s+1)(s+2)^4}\right]_{(t)}=$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s+1}-\frac{s^3+7s^2+17s+15}{(s+2)^4}\right]_{(t)}=$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{1+s}-\frac{1}{(s+2)^4}-\frac{1}{(s+2)^3}-\frac{1}{(s+2)^2}-\frac{1}{s+2}\right]_{(t)}=$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{1+s}-\frac{1}{(s+2)^4}-\frac{1}{(s+2)^3}-\frac{1}{(s+2)^2}-\frac{1}{s+2}\right]_{(t)}=$$

---

Now, use:

- $$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s+1}\right]_{(t)}=e^{-t}$$
- $$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s+2}\right]_{(t)}=e^{-2t}$$

  ---

$$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[-\frac{1}{(s+2)^4}-\frac{1}{(s+2)^3}-\frac{1}{(s+2)^2}\right]_{(t)}+e^{-t}-e^{-2t}=$$

---

Now, use:

- $$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{(s+x)^n}\right]_{(t)}=\frac{t^{n-1}}{e^{tx}\Gamma[n]}$$

  ---

$$e^{-t}-e^{-2t}-\frac{t^{4-1}}{e^{2t}\Gamma[4]}-\frac{t^{3-1}}{e^{2t}\Gamma[3]}-\frac{t^{2-1}}{e^{2t}\Gamma[2]}=$$
$$e^{-t}-e^{-2t}-\frac{t^3}{e^{2t}\Gamma[4]}-\frac{t^2}{e^{2t}\Gamma[3]}-\frac{t}{e^{2t}\Gamma[2]}=$$
$$e^{-t}-e^{-2t}-\frac{t^3}{6e^{2t}}-\frac{t^2}{2e^{2t}}-\frac{t}{e^{2t}}$$

Comment: I appreciate it for providing me the solution. I would have never though it would be this complected.

Comment: @Abdulrahman You're welcome! No one said that math would be easy, buddy :)

Comment: Usually I solve inverse functions by using the method mentioned above. But it seems there's a difference in this case.

Comment: @Abdulrahman I don't know if you study math?